# How to play two or more audio clips simultaneously using MediaPlayer (android)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I and my friend are creating an android app. We almost did it... The app will play two sounds simultaneously at first run, but in the second run it will throw some errors and attains ANR state. How to fix this? Check the logcat and code below.

**Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,Runnable {

    boolean mBound = false;
    Button btn1,btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    MediaPlayer yourStereo;

    MediaPlayer myStereo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_button);
         btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_button);
         btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.c_button);
         btn4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d_button);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        myStereo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brb);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btn3.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                btn4.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        try {
                            myStereo.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        myStereo.setLooping(true);
                        myStereo.start();
                        myStereo.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                myStereo.setLooping(true);
                                myStereo.release();
                                try {
                                    myStereo.prepare();
                                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                myStereo.start();
                            }
                        });
                        // pause music here

                        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                myStereo.stop();
                                btn4.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                                btn3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        });
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // play music here
            btn1.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
            btn2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            yourStereo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pl);
            yourStereo.setLooping(true);
            try {
                yourStereo.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                    yourStereo.start();
                    yourStereo.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            yourStereo.setLooping(true);
                            yourStereo.release();
                            try {
                                yourStereo.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            yourStereo.start();
                        }
                    });
            // pause music here

            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    yourStereo.stop();
                    btn2.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                    btn1.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
07-08 11:44:17.245: W/System.err(2659): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-08 11:44:17.261: W/System.err(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:17.261: W/System.err(2659):     at com.example.sleepsimulator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-08 11:44:17.269: W/System.err(2659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:20.534: W/KeyCharacterMap(2659): Can't open keycharmap file
07-08 11:44:20.534: W/KeyCharacterMap(2659): Error loading keycharmap file
07-08 11:44:20.534: W/KeyCharacterMap(2659): Using default keymap
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFF8E
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at com.example.sleepsimulator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-08 11:44:26.636: W/System.err(2659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:26.636: E/MediaPlayer(2659): start called in state 64
07-08 11:44:26.636: E/MediaPlayer(2659): error (-38, 0)
07-08 11:44:34.643: E/MediaPlayer(2659): stop called in state 0
07-08 11:44:34.643: E/MediaPlayer(2659): error (-38, 0)
07-08 11:44:34.643: E/MediaPlayer(2659): Error (-38,0)
07-08 11:44:34.651: W/System.err(2659): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at com.example.sleepsimulator.MainActivity$1$1.onCompletion(MainActivity.java:67)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1475)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/System.err(2659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:34.675: W/dalvikvm(2659): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:950)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at com.example.sleepsimulator.MainActivity$1$1.onCompletion(MainActivity.java:75)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1475)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-08 11:44:34.683: E/AndroidRuntime(2659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to calling `.release()` followed by `.prepare()` in your `onCompletionListener`

`.release()` releases all resources and should really only be called if you don't want to use the `MediaPlayer` at all any more, for example, on exit of your app.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)

Therefore your call to `.prepare()` after `.release()` is failing because it doesn't know what to prepare.

If you're just playing the same file again you can just call `.start()` again onCompletion. I believe it'll seek back to the beginning. No need to release and prepare again.

Also if you are using `.create()` there is no need to call `.prepare()` at all as it will already be in a prepared state.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri, android.view.SurfaceHolder)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder%29)